# custom Ionic slides component {Slides} import reference only updates last created slide component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Expected behavior: When I add multiple ionic slides components into a page I should be able to reference those slides and update their properties based on screen size.

Current behavior: When I have multiple ionic slides components on a page and attempt to update their properties based on screen size only the slide component that was created last actually updates with new settings.

**MovieSliderComponent.html**

```
<ion-slides #Slides class="slides" *ngIf="movies.length > 0" centeredSlides="true" loop="true" slidesPerView="3">
```

*I add a reference to slides in my html.*

**MovieSliderComponent.ts**

```
@ViewChild('Slides') slider: Slides;
```

*I apply the reference to a variable.*

**Home.html**

```
<movie-slider #Slider id="nowPlaying" *ngIf="mdata.inTheatres.length > 0" [movies]="mdata.inTheatres">

<movie-slider #Slider id="nowPlayingNearYou" *ngIf="mdata.nearbyShowings.length > 0" [movies]="mdata.nearbyShowings">

<movie-slider #Slider id="genreSuggestions" *ngIf="mdata.suggestedByGenre.length > 0" [movies]="mdata.suggestedByGenre" [showGenres]="true">
```

*I include my component in my page html three times.*

**Home.ts**

```
@ViewChildren('Slider') Slides: MovieSliderComponent[];
```

*I reference each of my slides in a variable;*

```
setSlidesPerView() {

 if(this.platform.width() >= 1200) {
   this.Slides.forEach((slider) => slider.slider.slidesPerView = 5);
   console.log(this.platform.width());
 }

 else if(this.platform.width() >= 319 && this.platform.width() < 1200) {
   this.Slides.forEach((slider) => slider.slider.slidesPerView = 3);
 }

 else if(this.platform.width() < 319) {
   this.Slides.forEach((slider) => slider.slider.slidesPerView = 1);
 }

 this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

*I attempt to change each of my sliders slidesPerView option but only the slide with slide-id-2 which is the slider last created gets updated.*

A link to my original issue @ionic-team/ionic-v3
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling slides.resize and slides.update on each instance of slides.